# Optimization strategies for finding a no re-visit graph traversal path (all vertices)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-algorithm

In an effort to dust off my somewhat rusty programming skills I'm trying to solve this graph traversal problem I ran across.

I want to find a path that visits all coordinates (vertices) on a 10x10 grid. There are some movement restrictions like only being able to move 3 steps in either direction (x+/-3 OR y+/-3) or 2 steps diagonally (x+/-2 AND y+/-2). From what I understand these restrictions don't really matter much since it's still just a graph with vertices and edges and I can model this easily enough in my solution.

I got so far as to being able to solve this problem for a 6x6 grid using a "simple" DFS strategy (at least I think that's what I've produced :). But going bigger than that I run into performance problems since the O(n) of my algorithm is kinda crap. 7x7 takes like 45 mins on my computer so 10x10 is just forget-about-it.

I figured out that a 5x5 grid can always be solved so I guess one viable strat would be to divide the 10x10 into 4x5x5. But that doesn't feel like a proper solution and even tho it would solve grids with sides of multiples of 5 I would still not be able to solve 8x8 and 11x11 etc.

**So my question here is about what strategies can be applied to optimize for this particular problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem), which is NP-complete for arbitrary graphs. This means there is no known efficient algorithm, so trying to solve this for arbitrary graphs will be fairly fruitless.

Instead, use the fact that you're solving it on a *grid*. You can simply go row-by-row, turning around at the ends.

If you have a limited set of moves you can do on a grid you can also look at [knight's tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour) literature.

Comment: That's probably why the movement constraints are what they are, to not make it so easy despite being a grid. Excuse me if you did consider that, and if so, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @OskarLund The movement constraints are critical then, I must've misunderstood them from your question. Can you clarify them a bit more? Because how I read them you can always just take one step the right/left/down which should be enough.

Comment: Maybe it's easier described in coordinates. So on a grid if you are on [0,0] you can only move to [3,0], [2,2] and [0,3]. Think similar to the Knight in chess. The [3-6,3-6] coordinates have all 8 directions available.

Comment: Upvote for link. I've struggled to even find the right description of the problem to do research. Thanks!

Comment: @OskarLund Another relevant search term might be 'knight's tour'.

Comment: Another very good tip! I implemented the Warnsdorff's rule mentioned in the  Wikipedia article on Knights Tour and it's like magic! My first basic implementation without any backtracking to try different paths fails to solve for a 6x6 board but spits out solutions for 10x10 and 12x12 (what I've tested so far) in a few ms! Many thanks!

If you care to edit Knights Tour into your answer, since it was key to the efficient solution, I'll accept it. Cheers!